# Optimize Delivery of Third Party Widgets - TripAdvisor

Tags: javascript, widget, tripadvisor

I am working on a website that uses the widgets to show reviews and such from the TripAdvisor website. However, according to Google's Page Speed Analytics, they are harming the performance of my website. Specifically, neither the CSS nor JavaScript are minified and the images are not optimized. Build tools such as [CSSNano](http://cssnano.co/) cannot be used in this situation (to my knowledge) since they come from a third-party. Typically, from my experience, when a third-party script is loaded from a CDN or similar, a minified version is available, but I do not believe this is the case in this instance. I looked at [Google's Page Speed Module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/) for the server, but I have IIS, and I am not positive it would work anyway (since the scripts are pulled from TripAdvisor rather than hosted on my server).

For reference, the widget renders as follows:

```
    <!-- TripAdvisor sidebar -->

<div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs"><div id="TA_selfserveprop522" class="TA_selfserveprop"><div id="CDSWIDSSP" class="widSSP widSSPnarrow" style="width: 240px;"> <div class="widSSPData"> <div class="widSSPBranding"> <dl> <dt> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"></a> </dt> <dt class="widSSPTagline">Know better. Book better. Go better.</dt> </dl> </div><!--/ cdsBranding--> <div class="widSSPComponent"> <div class="widSSPSummary"> <dl> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2271346-d1845701-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Suites_St_Louis_South_I_55-Mehlville_Saint_Louis_Missouri.html" onclick="ta.cds.handleTALink(11900,this);return true;" rel="nofollow"> <dt class="widSSPH18">Hampton Inn &amp; Suites St. Louis/South I-55</dt> </a> </dl> </div><!--/ cdsSummary--> </div><!--/ cdsComponent--> <div class="widSSPComponent widSSPOptional"> <div class="widSSPTrvlRtng"> <dl> <dt class="widSSPH11">TripAdvisor Traveler Rating</dt> <dd> <div class="widSSPOverall"> <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span> <div>Based on <b>1,291</b> traveler reviews</div> </div><!--/ overall --> </dd> </dl> </div> </div><!--/ cdsComponent --> <div class="widSSPWrap widSSPOptional"> <div class="widSSPInformation"> <div class="widSSPWrap"> <div class="widSSPPopIdx widSSPSingle"> <b>TripAdvisor Ranking</b> <span class="widSSPPopIdxData"> <span class="widSSPPopIdxData widSSPPopIdxNumbers"> <sup>#</sup>1 of 2 </span> hotels in Mehlville </span> </div><!--/ popIdx--> </div><!--/ cdsWrap--> </div><!--/ cdsInformation--> </div><!--/ cdsWrap--> <div class="widSSPComponent widSSPOptional"> <dl class="widSSPReviews"> <dt class="widSSPH11">Most Recent Traveler Reviews</dt> <dd class="widSSPOneReview"> <ul class="widSSPBullet"> <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Jun 28, 2017:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Hampton Inn &amp; Suites was GREAT!!!!”</span> </li> <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Jun 27, 2017:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“We Are Family!”</span> </li> <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Jun 27, 2017:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“A Great Experience in a Time of...”</span> </li> <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Jun 27, 2017:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“St Louis attractions trip”</span> </li> <li> <span class="widSSPDate">Jun 27, 2017:</span> <span class="widSSPQuote">“Too Pricey, Not So Nicey”</span> </li> </ul><!--/ bullet--> </dd><!--/ hReview--> </dl> </div> <div class="widSSPAll"> <ul class="widSSPReadReview"> <li><a href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2271346-d1845701-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Suites_St_Louis_South_I_55-Mehlville_Saint_Louis_Missouri.html" id="allreviews" onclick="ta.cds.handleTALink(11900,this);window.open(this.href, 'newTAWindow', 'toolbar=1,resizable=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=600'); return false" rel="nofollow">Read reviews</a></li> </ul> <ul class="widSSPWriteReview"> <li><a href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/UserReview-g2271346-d1845701-Hampton_Inn_Suites_St_Louis_South_I_55-Mehlville_Saint_Louis_Missouri.html" id="writereview" onclick="ta.cds.handleTALink(11900,this);window.open(this.href, 'newTAWindow', 'toolbar=1,resizable=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=600'); return false" rel="nofollow">Write a review</a></li> </ul> </div><!--/ cdsAll--> <div class="widSSPLegal">© 2017 TripAdvisor LLC</div><!--/ cdsLegal--> </div><!--/ cdsData--> </div><!--/ CDSPOP.cdsBx--> <img id="ta_tracking_selfserveprop_google" style="height:1px;width:1px;border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1020463497/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0&amp;data=POS%3Den_US%3Bmobile%3DN%3Bhrental_id%3D1845701%3BPropId%3D1845701%3Btravel_destid%3D2271346%3Bservlet%3DWidget%3Bwidget_name%3Dselfserveprop"><img id="ta_tracking_selfserveprop_criteo" style="height:1px;width:1px;border-style:none;" src="//widget.criteo.com/event?a=an%3Dweb-widget-tripadvisor.com%26cn%3Dus%26ln%3Den&amp;v=4.1.0&amp;p0=e%3Dce%26widget_type%3Dselfserveprop&amp;p1=e%3Dexd%26site_type%3Dd&amp;p2=e%3Dvp%26p%3D1845701&amp;p3=e%3Ddis%26a%3D%255Ban%25253Dweb-widget-tripadvisor.com%252526cn%25253Dus%252526ln%25253Den%255D&amp;rt=gif"></div><script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=522&amp;locationId=1845701&amp;lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=false&amp;display_version=2"></script><script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-selfserveprop?border=false&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;locationId=1845701&amp;display_version=2&amp;uniq=522&amp;rating=true&amp;lang=en_US&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true"></script></div>
<div class="col-sm-12  visible-sm visible-xs hidden-lg hidden-md"><div id="TA_cdsratingsonlywide284" class="TA_cdsratingsonlywide"><div id="CDSRATINGWIDGET284" class="cdsROW white  shadow   border   wide " style="width: 1px;"> <div id="CDSROWCONTAINER284" class="cdsROWContainer" style="width: auto;"> <!--[if lte IE 7]>       <table border="0" cellspacing="0">         <tr>           <td>    <div id="CDSROWLOGO284" class="cdsComponent logo">                                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img  src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>   </div> </td>           <td>  <div id="CDSROWLOC284" class="cdsComponent cdsLocName">     <a id="CDSLOCINNER" target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2271346-d1845701-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Suites_St_Louis_South_I_55-Mehlville_Saint_Louis_Missouri.html" onclick="ta.cds.handleTALink($cdsConfig.getMcid()); return true;">Hampton Inn & Suites St. Louis/South I-55</a>   </div> </td>           <td>  <div id="CDSROWRATING284" class="cdsComponent cdsRating">     <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span>         <span>       1,291 Reviews     </span>   </div> </td>         </tr>       </table>       <![endif]--> <!--[if gte IE 8]><!--> <div id="CDSROWLOGO284" class="cdsComponent logo"> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"></a> </div> <div id="CDSROWLOC284" class="cdsComponent cdsLocName" style="max-width: 1px;"> <a id="CDSLOCINNER" target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2271346-d1845701-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Suites_St_Louis_South_I_55-Mehlville_Saint_Louis_Missouri.html" onclick="ta.cds.handleTALink($cdsConfig.getMcid()); return true;" rel="nofollow">Hampton Inn &amp; Suites St. Louis/South I-55</a> </div> <div id="CDSROWRATING284" class="cdsComponent cdsRating"> <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span> <span> 1,291 Reviews </span> </div> <!--<![endif]--> </div> </div>  <img id="ta_tracking_cdsratingsonlywide_google" style="height:1px;width:1px;border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1020463497/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0&amp;data=POS%3Den_US%3Bmobile%3DN%3Bhrental_id%3D1845701%3BPropId%3D1845701%3Btravel_destid%3D2271346%3Bservlet%3DWidget%3Bwidget_name%3Dcdsratingsonlywide"><img id="ta_tracking_cdsratingsonlywide_criteo" style="height:1px;width:1px;border-style:none;" src="//widget.criteo.com/event?a=an%3Dweb-widget-tripadvisor.com%26cn%3Dus%26ln%3Den&amp;v=4.1.0&amp;p0=e%3Dce%26widget_type%3Dcdsratingsonlywide&amp;p1=e%3Dexd%26site_type%3Dd&amp;p2=e%3Dvp%26p%3D1845701&amp;p3=e%3Ddis%26a%3D%255Ban%25253Dweb-widget-tripadvisor.com%252526cn%25253Dus%252526ln%25253Den%255D&amp;rt=gif"></div><script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlywide&amp;uniq=284&amp;locationId=1845701&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=true&amp;shadow=true&amp;display_version=2"></script><script src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-cdsratingsonlywide?border=true&amp;shadow=true&amp;locationId=1845701&amp;display_version=2&amp;uniq=284&amp;lang=en_US"></script></div>


</div>
```

I am starting to think it is simply not possible to optimize the widgets. However, they do seem to take a notable toll on the website, so I would like to see if anyone has relevant experience with these widgets or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with this issue right now. Removing the widget from the site results in a 60% improvement in site speed. You can't alter their widget code in any meaningful way to improve it, so it's better to periodically screenshot its current rendered view and crop it into a small .png that you place on your site. It's not at all clear whether it provides all that much credibility value to people anyways.